# Сортировка в django

Tags: django

Есть две модели

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Тема", max_length=250)
    text = models.TextField("Текст")
    date_now = models.DateTimeField("Дата создания", auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Tag(models. Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Модель `Tag` нужна для добавление тегов к постам и вывода постов с определенными тегами на отдельную страницу. 
Если на основной странице с постами, я могу выполнить сортировку постов по дате добавления так

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by('-date_now')
```

То на странице с постами определенным тегом сортировка не работает (что очевидно, ведь в модели Tag нет ничего связанного с датой).

```
def tag_detail(request, slug):
    tag = Tag.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    context = {'tag': tag, 'tags':tags}
    return render(request, 'loglists/tag_detail.html', context)
```

Немного запутался, как это проще реализовать? Устанавливать отношение один к одному, или как?

Comment: Покажите код представления для страницы постов с определённым тегом.

Comment: `def tag_detail (request, slug):
    tag = Tag.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    context = {'tag': tag,
               'tags':tags}
    return render(request, 'loglists/tag_detail.html', context)`

Comment: Не вижу, чтобы у вас в этом представлении вообще посты выводились. Вы делаете это в шаблоне? Если да, то покажите и его тоже.

Comment: Вывожу обычным циклом  `{% for tag in post.tags.all %} <div class="post-date col-md-12"><a href="{% url 'loglists:tag_detail' tag.slug %}">{{tag.title}}</a> {% empty %} <p> Пусто </p>`

Comment: Выводите теги, а спрашиваете про посты.

Comment: Тэги же связанны с постами ManyToManyField'ом, post.tags.all так забираю все посты с данным тегом

Comment: Нет, так вы получаете все теги какого-то конкретного поста, а не наоборот.